# Check if user is monthly active app user

Tags: facebook

I know I can get the insights of how many monthly app users my app has by running

```
SELECT monthly_active_users FROM application WHERE app_id=00000000000000
```

What I'd like to do is get the ID's of all those active app users. Or, if given a user ID, check if that user ID is an active user of my app.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do that using FQL. You should track users who use your app in your local DB and then query it. At least I have not found this in the docs and never seen this.

Here is the definition of "monthly active users" http://joshuaopinion.com/2011/01/monthly-active-users-mau-definition-for-facebook/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I track who's using my app. But Facebooks definition of "monthly active user" might differ from what I'd define it to. Anyways, if it ain't possible i'll definetly resort to querying my own DB.

Comment: @SoroushHakami I added a link to the definition to the answer